# Mule 4 Object store and caching - need to store records from Db in cache and then use them from cache

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

I am using Mule 4.4 on premise .
My use case is to load some static data from a database table and to store it in a cache.
I need to periodically also refresh the cache ( say every 24 hours )
The static data is employee data .

So here is my code with scheduler which will populate cache:

```
<flow name="load_cache" doc:id="8eaefe57-6de8-4d4f-97d5-fa181ea54b8b" >
        <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler" doc:id="b3fb9ce7-7254-481e-a137-d37ed1cc30a3" >
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <fixed-frequency />
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
        <ee:transform doc:name="emp data from db" doc:id="b5d11958-3ea7-4596-9aed-51c616ae67f0" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
[
    {
        "id" : "001",
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "id" : "002",
        "name" : "Jane"
    }
]]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="da8ec47c-7b34-4707-ac78-6ffd433fb40b" >
            <os:store doc:name="Store" doc:id="d139954b-a4b7-4351-9463-8baccb5e2aba" key="#[payload.id]" objectStore="Object_store">
                <os:value ><![CDATA[#[payload.name]]]></os:value>
            </os:store>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
```

here the transform component 'emp data from db' is simply a transform component simulating results from db.
While storing in Object store the `key` used is the `id` of each object

So now that the object store is getting periodically populated I would like to test - so have defined a sinple flow with a HTTP Listener

```
<flow name="header_pass_01Flow" doc:id="dc0c28a7-c277-4192-b641-e73af8afbde3" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="57e56cd6-a47e-456b-8c6d-e57627c673b8" path="/caching/*" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config"/>
        <set-variable value='#["001"]' doc:name="get emp name for empId" doc:id="130a350e-d23b-41f6-86c3-fe8104b63d3f" variableName="id"/>
        <ee:cache doc:name="Cache" doc:id="a11f6da2-d24e-4a69-a0b1-647c0b6dfda8" cachingStrategy-ref="Caching_Strategy">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="fdeaaeff-06df-45d7-8c1f-410f343ae4e8" message="Not found in cache"/>
        </ee:cache>
    </flow>
```

The cache uses an underlying Object store ( the same one which is getting populated by the scheduler.

However - even though I am setting a variable `id` with the value of `001` before reaching cache the request always gets a 'miss' i.e never finds this id in the cache .... not sure why ?

Here is the complete code of the other components:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="f1bec56d-de65-4a93-913d-07a7426d6bf6" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="9091" />
    </http:listener-config>
    
    <os:object-store name="Object_store" doc:name="Object store" doc:id="152be16e-2fd9-4d48-8310-3d6d45be4bff" maxEntries="10" entryTtl="2" entryTtlUnit="HOURS" />
    <ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy" doc:id="79383e4a-b907-450d-92c9-9d15b1efbb81" objectStore="Object_store" />
```

How do I ensure that the data I am populating via scheduler is available in cache such that on querying I get data from cache ?

am expecting data to be retrieved from cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are confusing the functionality of the Cache Scope and of the Object Store. The Cache Scope uses internally an Object Store to store the information to catch. You **should not** use that Object Store directly to put the values. Cache Scope automatically catches the information that enters the scope when executing its flow.

In your example you should put the transformation from the first flow inside the Cache Scope of the second. Keep the logger to verify when it executes or not.

Comment: thanks @aled so you are right moved the transform component into the cache scope and after first call when I am looking for same data again , it is being retrieved from the cache . So looks like I cannot forcefully refresh the cache ( underlying object store ) using a scheduler  since as you said the cache component is populating underlying object store on a 'miss' .

Comment: I recommend to also look at @HarshankBansal answer for additional details.

Comment: @boomslaw You can 'forcefully' refresh cache (FYI this is called pre-caching) like you just did. Just instead of a HTTP Listener, your flow will be triggered from a scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a miss everytime because you have not added a `keyGenerationExpression` in your `object-store-caching-strategy`. Therefore it is generating a key by hashing the payload.

Your cache strategy should look like this after adding it

```xml
<ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy" doc:id="79383e4a-b907-450d-92c9-9d15b1efbb81"keyGenerationExpression="#[vars.id]" objectStore="Object_store" />
```

Having said that, I remember trying the same some time back, and I got a serialization error. Looks like cache scope uses its own serialization to store and deserialize after retrieving it.

As suggested by [@aled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76262682/10946202), you should try to replace your `os:store` operation with `cache` scope by putting a simple transformer that will output your desired value.

Comment: thanks yes it worked with what @aled suggested and yes trying to use a ```keyGenerationExpression``` results in a serialization error ```com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.cache.internal.ObjectStoreCachingStrategy: Unable to retrieve object from cache. Verify if there is a serialization compatibility problem
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mule.runtime.api.metadata.TypedValue cannot be cast to org.mule.runtime.core.api.event.CoreEvent```